# Loading custom js file on the admin page through plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm new to the world of `Wordpress` and I just started developing my first `plugin`. 
When it's activated it should load one javascript file to `wp-admin/post-new.php` (Add new post) page.

Here is how I tried to do this:

**Plugin**

```
class WP_Blog_Customizer{
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_dependencies') ); 
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'wpa_install' ) );
        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'wpa_uninstall' ) );
    }
    public function load_dependencies(){
        wp_enqueue_script('blog-customizer', plugins_url('js/blog-customizer.js', __FILE__),array('jquery'),'1.0.0', true);
    }
}
new WP_Blog_Customizer();
```

**wp-admin/post-new.php**

```
if(is_plugin_active( 'blog-customizer/blog-customizer.php' )){
        $plugin = new WP_Blog_Customizer();
}
```

Shouldn't this `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_dependencies') );` from the `__construct` of my plugin class include this js file?

**Note**

This js file is located under the js folder in my plugin's folder, so the path is correct.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working, and how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loading scripts in admin side we have to use [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) hook. So something like this should do the job:

```
class WP_Blog_Customizer{
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_dependencies') ); 
        //...other constructor things
    }
    public function load_dependencies( $hook ){
        if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' ) { // for loading script also on post edit screen use ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' )
            wp_enqueue_script('blog-customizer', plugins_url('js/blog-customizer.js', __FILE__),array('jquery'),'1.0.0', true);
        }
    }
}
new WP_Blog_Customizer();
```